# How to convert dates in m/d/y and m-d-y to a single format in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, date-formatting

activity$ActivityDate = as.POSIXct(activity$ActivityDate, format="%d/%m/%y", tz=Sys.timezone()) returns NA in ActivityDate and Date columns in R

activity$ActivityDate = as.POSIXct(activity$ActivityDate, format="%d/%m/%y", tz=Sys.timezone()) ends up with NA in ActivityDate column in R

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess what you would like to achieve based on your question title - it would help if you could include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/10363163) and some prose describing your problem.

It seems that `lubridate`'s parsing functions might do what you need:

```r
ActivityDate <-  c("07/31/2022", "07-31-2022")
lubridate::mdy(ActivityDate)
#> [1] "2022-07-31" "2022-07-31"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>